# mySQL string matching

Tags: php, mysql, sql, regex

I am needing to query my database to find records that fall between 2 dates (this is simple enough) however I need to refine the search so that it only finds records where the email falls within certain constraints, basically I need to delete any row that falls between 2 dates and has a format of

x.xxxxxXXXXX@xxxxxxxx.xxx

basically I need to look for email address that start with a letter followed by full stop and have 5 numbers before the @ sign.  Is this possible with mySQL and if so how, and if not how could I search for these email address with PHP?

Comment: Exactly 5 number must exist before @ or any other char may exists. Please give any example of such type of email address.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use regular expressions. MySQL 5.1 supports these: [documentation page](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/regexp.html). This also can be done in PHP using [preg_match](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php).

You regurlar expression could look like: `[a-zA-Z]\.[a-zA-Z]+[0-9]{5}@.+`

Answer (score 0):

You could also use like, if you find it useful. Example

```
LIKE '_.__________@______.___'
```

However, it will not detect numbers. 
In that case you have to use regex

[docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/string-comparison-functions.html#operator_like)

Regex should be like this: (changed from example above)

```
[a-zA-Z]{1}\.[a-zA-Z]+[0-9]{5}@([_a-z0-9\-])\.[a-zA-Z]
```